# Create and fill combo box with mysql data with php

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I have done google searches and found several answers but I cannot get this to work. I am trying to read a field from ym mysql database and create and populate a combo box containing those values. The database connection works but all I get is a list of the values and no combo box. I am posting my code, along with the results.

```
<?php
$cn=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name",$cn) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT LoadNumber FROM tblLoads";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<select name="loads" size=1>
<?
while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value=" .$ri['LoadNumber'] . ">" . $ri['LoadNumber'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select> "
?>
```

Here is my output:

```
1637825
1637933
1638102
1638109
1638574
1638683
>
```

Please, this is driving me crazy, i don't see what I am doing wrong. it does not create the combo box.

Comment: Can you check and provide your generated HTML? By glancing at your code I noticed that you're not wrapping `$ri['LoadNumber']`'s value in quotes, for example.

Comment: you didn't close this `echo "</select> "` and make sure short tags are enabled. Error reporting would have signaled that "syntax" error which is **off-topic**.

Comment: This question has been viewed over 2500 times, and noone can give me a positive vote? this was a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are complicating your code! Some part of it is wrapped in PHP and part of it is not.

Change this...

```
<select name="loads" size=1>
<?
while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value=" .$ri['LoadNumber'] . ">" . $ri['LoadNumber'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select> "
?>
```

To this...

```
<select name="loads" id="loads">
<?php while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $ri['LoadNumber'] ?>"><?php echo $ri['LoadNumber'] ?></option>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

Finally... you should stop coding in `mysql_` !!! It has been deprecated and will soon cease to exist. When that happens, all of your sites using `mysql_` code will stop functioning.

You should really be learning [pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: thanks all. also figured out I had it in body, moved it to header and it worked somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this.
<select name="loads" size=1>
<?php while($ri =  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value=" .$ri['LoadNumber'] . ">" . $ri['LoadNumber'] . "</option>";?>
<select>
```

just move the last select from the php script.

Comment: add that to your answer and delete from the comments

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer: simple and more understandable than the accepted answer.